# Regex for Mr. and Mrs. replacement

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex to replace the First part of the string (Mr. or Ms. - ) e.g. "Mr. some name" or "Ms. some name" with  their full equivalents. so  that "Mr. some name" becomes "Mister some name" and "Miss some name". I can do that  separately for each case like that:

```
function fn(str) {
  if (/^Mr./.test(str)) {
    return str.replace(/^Mr./, "Mister");
  }
  else if (/^Ms./.test(str)) {
    return str.replace(/^Ms./, "Miss");
  }
}

console.log(fn("Ms. Name")) // will output "Miss Name"
```

But I have a feeling that it should have "one string" solution.

Comment: There is a semantic difference between Ms and Miss. http://www.softschools.com/difference/ms_vs_miss_vs_mrs/8/

Comment: `/^Mr./` also matches "Mrx"…

Comment: no, there isn't, really, because both of what you're searching for and what you're replacing with are different.

Comment: You can try using Ternary operator. `condition?true:false` - I think it's a one line approach.

Comment: @spender, that's was just a simple case that came up to my mind, the real case is  different, but thanks for pointing out

Comment: As @spender notes, only "Mr." is an abbreviation, so only "Mr." could be expanded. Ms. != Miss, and the only possible expansion of "Mrs." is "Missus", which is archaic. You don't even need to use a regex. Just test `if str[0,3] == "Mr.")`... Even if they were all abbreviations,  there's no pattern there to be matched by a regular expression so it's a terrible candidate for pattern matching using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `"^Mr\."` as your regex.

`.` without escaping matches every character.

---

And a for one line:

```
str = str.replace("^Mr\.", "Mister").replace("^Ms\.", "Miss");
```

Comment: Don't replace "Ms." with "Miss". They're not equivalent. This isn't a knock against this solution, I just don't want later viewers to think it's valid English.

Comment: Isn't that 'Mrs'? Not a native though.

Comment: See @spender's link in his comment to the OP's question. "Ms." is intentionally ambiguous and is not an abbreviation (neither is Mrs.). As used in American English (and modern English-English) "Ms." is not an abbreviation.  Wikipedia has a good article on "Ms.".

Answer (score 4):

To do it in a single operation, this'll do:

```
str.replace(/^M(r|s)\./, function(m) {
    return {
        'Mr.': 'Mister',
        'Ms.': 'Miss'
    }[m];
});
```

1. Use a regex which matches both possible cases, `M(r|s)\.`.
2. Use a callback function to figure out which value it matched and translate it into the result, done here with a simple key-value object.

Though while this may simple enough in this easy case, this approach can get really complex and unreadable very quickly. Doing individual replacements may be the saner option.

Comment: @PeterLeger next time please comment on an answer instead of single handedly changing it. now it sparked a maybe flow of subsequent edits, apparently because your edit is faulty.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: You are right! Sorry for that. I'd like to edit again to put it into the original. Next time I'll comment. Thank your very much for the hint!

Comment: @deceze, what about [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40292933/2545680) ?

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions don't fit here.

Regex solutions all have to re-match each specific prefix to a non-patterned expanded value.

That means we have to match our prefixes twice (deceze's solution) or make redundant calls to `.replace()` (Uriel Eli's solution) in order to shoehorn this solution into one or more regular expressions.

This is wasteful and overcomplicated.
`String.prototype.substring()` is a far better fit than `.replace()` since the problem can't be adequately generalized to a pattern.

```
function (name) {
    return ("Mr." == name.substring(0,3))?"Mister"+name.substring(3):name;
}
```

Don't replace "Ms." with "Miss"; please check @spender's link for an explanation.

Comment: _Regex solutions all have to re-match each specific prefix to a non-patterned expanded value. That means we have to match our prefixes twice (deceze's solution)_ - can you please elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: deceze's solution (and yours) had to match using the regex first, and then it had to compare the matched value to the static strings `'Mr.'` (and for deceze's solution, also `'Ms.'`): two comparisons. There's no better way to do it while still using regular expressions,but it's still overkill. I'd argue that Uriel's solution isn't even using regular expressions. Sure he's calling a function that can handle regular expressions, but he's using it to do string comparison, not pattern matching. Plus he had to do it twice, where at least one comparison was always going to fail to match.

Comment: but yours also uses comparison `("Mr." == name.substring(0,3))?"Mister"+name.substring(3):name`, what's the difference between mine and yours?

Comment: I didn't have to compare it to a regular expression first, so I only made one comparison.

Comment: I think I see you point now. You're saying the although I do one comparison, the regex does multiple, correct?

Comment: No, I mean you do a comparison with the regex, and then you still have to do a second comparison (string compare) after that so you may as well have just done two string compares since they're far less costly (and easier to figure out) than regex comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Or without regex :

```
var transform =  str => str.split(" ").map((word, index) => {
     if (index === 0 && word === "Mr") return "Mister";
     if (index === 0 && word === "Ms") return "Miss";
     return word;
}).join(" ");
```

Comment: "need a regex to replace the First part of the string (Mr. or Ms. - )". This kind of specification is not clear enough ????????

Comment: And you're much more gifted for downvote and stupid testing than for desinging solution. I just offer a solution without regex. And this solution works perfectly now with a string with neither Mr nor Ms.

Comment: You're right that there's no benefit in trying to force the solution to use regular expressions here, especially since "Ms." can not be validly expanded to "Miss", though I assume you're just copying that error from the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also use regex like this `^M((r)|s)\.` and check for matching groups existence:

```
"Ms. hello".replace(/^M((r)|s)\./, function($1, $2, $3) {
    return $3 ? 'Mister' : 'Miss';
})
// Miss hello

"Mr. hello".replace(/^M((r)|s)\./, function($1, $2, $3) {
    return $3 ? 'Mister' : 'Miss';
})
// Mister hello
```

Comment: You can even reduce it to `^((Mr)|Ms)\.` (or even `^M((r)|s)\.`) because you don't need the content of the third capture group. Also, `g` in the regex is redundant because that tells the regex to match more than once per line, and this pattern can only occur at the very beginning. "Ms" isn't short for "Miss", so how about "Dr." and "Doctor" instead: `str.replace(/^((Mr)|Dr)\./, function (theWholeExpression,captureGroup1,captureGroup2) { return captureGroup2 ? 'Mister' : 'Doctor'; })` (or with a shorter regex: `str.replace(/^((M)|D)r\./, function (a,b,c) { return c ? 'Mister' : 'Doctor'; })`)

Comment: @LinuxDisciple, thanks, updated my answer. Are matching groups always found within the boundaries of a match?